# Coldfusion loop and remove rows if a particular row type exists

Tags: sql, coldfusion

column names: mastertransid, type_internal_id_int

Query returns 3 rows. For `type_internal_id_int` the value can either be `SalesOrd`, `ItemShip` or `CustInvc`

`mastertransid` is the same for all 3 rows and groups the three together

However if there is a record for `type_internal_id_int` and `it = CustInvc` then I need to hide the other two rows.

I've tried grouping my data using `<cfoutput group by="type_internal_id_int">` without any luck.

From the image I have included, I don't want customers to see SalesOrd or ItemShip, if a CustInvc value exists.

[image]

Comment: Just to add, if this type of record exists (type_internal_id_int = CustInvc) then I don't want to output the other two rows in that image (type_internal_id_int = SalesOrd and type_internal_id_int = ItemShip )

INV38723 378009 06/04/2021 $39.38 Paid In Full

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need an `order by` in your sql. Then put in an if condition if the criteria is met to hide the rows that come after.

Comment: Order by is done. Can you please provide me with an example of the if condition? @JamesAMohler

Comment: Filtering rows you don't want is best done in the query, not the display code.

Comment: Assuming you still need to keep the hidden rows, I would do a query of queries to eliminate the unneeded rows. Or when looping, use a conditional to show the ones you want.

Comment: This is far more a query issue and not really CF.